# the tensorflow docker gpu image doesn't detect my GPU

Tags: linux, docker, tensorflow, nvidia

Running the latest docker with:

```
docker run -it -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=/tf --ip 0.0.0.0 --no-browser --allow-root --NotebookApp.allow_origin='https://colab.research.google.com'
```

code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
```

gives me:

```
2020-07-27 19:44:03.826149: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2020-07-27 19:44:03.826179: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:313] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (-1)
2020-07-27 19:44:03.826201: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:163] no NVIDIA GPU device is present: /dev/nvidia0 does not exist
```

I'm on Pop_OS 20.04, have tried installing the CUDA drivers from the Pop repository as well as from NVidia. No dice. Any help appreciated.

Running

```
docker run --gpus all nvidia/cuda:10.0-base nvidia-smi
```

gives me:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.51.05    Driver Version: 450.51.05    CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 2080    On   | 00000000:09:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   52C    P5    15W / 225W |    513MiB /  7959MiB |     17%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As per the docs [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/docker) and [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker), you have to add a "gpus" argument when creating a the docker container to have gpu support.

So you should start your container something like this. The "--gpus all" makes all the gpus available on the host to be visible to the container.

```sh
docker run -it --gpus all -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=/tf --ip 0.0.0.0 --no-browser --allow-root --NotebookApp.allow_origin='https://colab.research.google.com'
```

Also you can try running nvidia-smi on the tensorflow image to quickly check if gpu is accessible on the container.

```sh
docker run -it --rm --gpus all tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter nvidia-smi
```

Would return this in my case.

```sh
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.100      Driver Version: 440.100      CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1070    Off  | 00000000:07:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   45C    P8     8W / 166W |    387MiB /  8116MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

As you can see, I'm running an older nvidia driver(440.100), so I cannot confirm that this would solve your problem. I'm also on Pop_OS 20.04 and didn't install anything other than docker along with dependencies and nvidia-container-toolkit.

Also I would highly suggest avoiding the latest tag when creating containers as it might cause you to unknowingly upgrade to a newer image. Go with version numbered images.

For example tensorflow/tensorflow:2.3.0-gpu-jupyter.

Comment: That did it! Maybe I'm wrong but it seems like the gpu flag shouldn't be necessary on an image made for GPU :(

Comment: I agree that there should be some sort of default gpu allocation, but I also think its a deliberate design choice for standardized use in small and as well as large scale enterprise setting. It would come in real handy when you have a ton of gpus and want to automate and distribute it among many users.

Comment: Note that you'll need to install the container runtime if you haven't already: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#gpu

Comment: @derekbaker783 good point, since op got nvidia-smi working in a container, i didn't add that in the answer.